# Uanable to bevel correctly , as per the image?

Tags: bevel

My edge bevels are going over one face not equally over both adjacent faces as per the tutorial, I am just a beginner so any help would be great.

[image: Left part is the tutorial how I want to bevel.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your object has non uniform scale. in object mode, apply scale (ctrl+A then scale).

Comment: @lemon thanks a lot !